# How to populate list adapter by retrieving firebase datas?

Tags: android, list, firebase-realtime-database, adapter, listadapter

I'm trying to query firebase databse to store child values in a holder inside a List Adapter. Where to store datasnapshot values to use them to init holders ?

The query for retrieving data from firebase is not working.

```
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = reference
            .child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_user_account_settings))
            .orderByChild(mContext.getString(R.string.field_user_id))
            .equalTo(getItem(position).getUser_id());
    Log.d(TAG, "getting the data");
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: getting the data 2");
            for ( DataSnapshot singleSnapshot :  dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: getting the data 3");

                holder.username.setText(
                      singleSnapshot.getValue(UserAccountSettings.class).getUsername());


                ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

                imageLoader.displayImage(
                        singleSnapshot.getValue(UserAccountSettings.class).getProfile_photo(),
                        holder.profileImage);
            }

        }
```

UserAccountSettings.class :

> public class UserAccountSettings implements Parcelable{
>
> ```
> private String description;
> private String display_name;
> private String profile_photo;
> private String username;
> private String website;
>
> public UserAccountSettings(String description, String display_name, String profile_photo, String username,
>                            String website) {
>     this.description = description;
>     this.display_name = display_name;
>     this.profile_photo = profile_photo;
>     this.username = username;
>     this.website = website;
> }
>
> public UserAccountSettings() {
>
> }
>
> protected UserAccountSettings(Parcel in) {
>     description = in.readString();
>     display_name = in.readString();
>     profile_photo = in.readString();
>     username = in.readString();
>     website = in.readString();
> }
>
> public static final Creator<UserAccountSettings> CREATOR = new Creator<UserAccountSettings>() {
>     @Override
>     public UserAccountSettings createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
>         return new UserAccountSettings(in);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public UserAccountSettings[] newArray(int size) {
>         return new UserAccountSettings[size];
>     }
> };
>
> public String getDescription() {
>     return description;
> }
>
> public void setDescription(String description) {
>     this.description = description;
> }
>
> public String getDisplay_name() {
>     return display_name;
> }
>
> public void setDisplay_name(String display_name) {
>     this.display_name = display_name;
> }
>
> public String getProfile_photo() {
>     return profile_photo;
> }
>
> public void setProfile_photo(String profile_photo) {
>     this.profile_photo = profile_photo;
> }
>
> public String getUsername() {
>     return username;
> }
>
> public void setUsername(String username) {
>     this.username = username;
> }
>
> public String getWebsite() {
>     return website;
> }
>
> public void setWebsite(String website) {
>     this.website = website;
> }
>
>
> @Override
> public String toString() {
>     return "UserAccountSettings{" +
>             "description='" + description + '\'' +
>             ", display_name='" + display_name + '\'' +
>             ", profile_photo='" + profile_photo + '\'' +
>             ", username='" + username + '\'' +
>             ", website='" + website + '\'' +
>             '}';
> }
>
> @Override
> public int describeContents() {
>     return 0;
> }
>
> @Override
> public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
>     dest.writeString(description);
>     dest.writeString(display_name);
>     dest.writeString(profile_photo);
>     dest.writeString(username);
>     dest.writeString(website);
> } }
> ```

Error :-
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.ekagra.project.Models.UserAccountSettings

I am expecting to retrieve text in holder.username and photo url in holder.profile image but the for loop seems to not even work because The Log "getting the data 3" is not displaying in the monitor.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could you check logcat is there any firebase related logs ?

Comment: Yep -  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.ekagra.project.Models.UserAccountSettings

Comment: You dont convert a datasnapshot object into your own class. You have to get the value of that object by `singleSnapshot.getValue()`

Comment: If you want to convert a snapshot into your own class, you might have to do it manually

Comment: What's the right way to do that ?

Comment: Please add your database structure and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamoI fixed it by removing the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

log the result that u got from the snap shot 
`Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: getting the data 3" + singleSnapshot);`

then tell me what you are getting. 
Also can you add an image of your database for refrence

Comment: I am getting - com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.ekagra.project.Models.UserAccountSettings   I have updated UserAccountSettings.class in the question

Comment: add the screenshot of the error and where the error is getting

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing the for loop.